# Remove an item on clicking using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-redux

An image gallery is a set of images with corresponding remove buttons. This is the HTML code for a gallery with two images:

```
<div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="URL1">
    <button class="remove">X</button>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="URL2">
    <button class="remove">X</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Implement the ImageGallery component that accepts a links prop and renders the gallery described above so that the first item in the links prop is the src attribute of the first image in the gallery. It should also implement the following logic: When the button is clicked, the image that is in the same div as the button should be removed from the gallery.

For example, after the first image has been removed from the gallery above, it's HTML code should look like this:

```
<div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="URL2">
    <button class="remove">X</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**This is the solution I have implemented, but it does not pass the test cases**

```
class ImageGallery extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

  }
  remove = e => {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
      document.getElementsByClassName("remove"),
      function(elem) {
        elem.onclick = () => elem.parentNode.remove();
      }
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.links.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={item} className="image">
              <img key={index} src={item} />{" "}
              <button className="remove" onClick={this.remove}>
                X
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

document.body.innerHTML = "<div id='root'> </div>";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const links = ["URL1", "URL2"];
ReactDOM.render(<ImageGallery links={links} />, rootElement);
document.querySelectorAll(".remove")[0].click();
console.log(rootElement.innerHTML);
```

Here is a sandbox demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/testdome-react-1-focus-7qbp1?file=/src/index.js

Please refer to Question number 5 for details regarding the test cases - https://www.testdome.com/d/react-js-interview-questions/304

Answer (score 0):

You don't need external event listeners and removing dom nodes if not good idea when you have react to do this. Here is how you can do this.

Updated sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/testdome-react-1-focus-4627z?file=/src/index.js

```js
class ImageGallery extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { links: props.links };
  }
  remove = url => {
    console.log(url)
    this.setState(state => ({
      links: state.links.filter(l => l !== url)
    }));
  };
  render() {
    const { links } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {links.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={item} className="image">
              <img key={index} src={item} alt="" />{" "}
              <button className="remove" onClick={() => this.remove(item)}>
                X
              </button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not working as expected as per the sandbox demo, please check once. Also I need to pass the test case - https://www.testdome.com/d/react-js-interview-questions/304

Check question 5

Comment: I added `document.querySelectorAll(".remove")[0].click();` line and test passed. check the updated sandbox

Comment: remove method is not removing the items, can you freeze the changes, so that I could check the working fiddler

Comment: Why do you need to return items from remove?

Comment: I am not understanding, the remove method is not deleting the items on your sandbox demo

Comment: Leave the sandbox. Copy code from above snippet and replace your `ImageGallery` component

Comment: how it is now working? I myself pasted code in Question 5 and test passed. You will see only one image in sandbox since code for test removes the first image using this line `document.querySelectorAll('.remove')[0].click();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211163/discussion-between-zapdos13-and-zohaib-ijaz).

Answer (score 0):

here is the correct answer

```
  class ImageGallery extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = { links: props.links };
   }
   remove = index => {
      var list = this.state.links
      list.splice(index,1);
      this.setState({links:list})
     };

  render() {
    return (
     <div>
      {this.state.links.map((item, index) => {
       return (
        <div key={item} className="image">
          <img key={index} src={item} alt="" />
          <button className="remove" onClick={() => this.remove(index)}>
            X
          </button>
        </div>
         );
       })}
     </div>
    );
   }
  }
    document.body.innerHTML = "<div id='root'> </div>";

  const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
   const links = ["www.goo.gl/kjzfbE", "www.goo.gl/d2JncW"];
  ReactDOM.render(<ImageGallery links={ links } />,
            rootElement);
  document.querySelectorAll('.remove')[0].click();
  console.log(rootElement.innerHTML);
```